# ELSE if block after if statement on overleaf throws error

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I want to implement a if else block like that

```
if A
  if B
    if C
       else if D
    end
   if E
   end
  end
end
```

Where **if C** and **if E** has same indentation. **if B** under **if A**. **if C** and **if E** both are under **if B**.

I used **\SetKwIF{If}{}{}{if}{}{ELSEIF}{else}{end if}** to set the rule of if and else

I also write it on overleaf to implement the above portion. I was unable to implement else if portion. If I write **else if*** overleaf throws errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\small\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}   % Set the Input
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output} %Set the Output
\SetKwIF{If}{}{}{if}{}{ELSEIF}{else}{end if}%
\begin{document}
\SetAlgoNoLine
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
\KwInput{abc}
\KwOutput{abc}
\KwData{abc}
\If{(A)}
    {
    \If{B}{
    \If{C}{
       do this
    }
    \ELSEIF{D}{
    Do this
    }
    
     \If{(E)}{
       do this
    }
    
    }
   }
       
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Error that I received

[image]

The package that I used for the algorithm \usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

Comment: Please don't add arbitrary tags. You're not using latex3 and overleaf is just your editor. That said, I don't know what you're asking or what you're trying to do. My best guess is that you are trying to typeset an algorithm. If so, please complete your code to make it a minimal working example If the problem is an error, provide the text of the error and a minimal non-working example we can use to reproduce it. Use backticks for inline code rather than bold.

Comment: Instead of text "the command that I used", just add the `\usepackage{algorithm2e}` to the top (as well as `\documentclass` and `\begin/\end{document}`).  It's much easier to help you if you have what you think should be a complete document that everyone can copy and paste.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Why does your error message include `\ELSIF` when your document uses `\ELSEIF`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fill the second argument of `\SetKwIF` to create the macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\SetKwIF{If}{ELSEIF}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{endif}

\begin{document}
\SetAlgoNoLine
\begin{algorithm}[!ht]
\uIf{C}{
   do this
}
\ELSEIF{D}{
Do this
}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your else if displayed in the small letters. However, mine is in capital letter **ELSEIF**. How can I change the display like you?

Comment: @Encipher Adjust the 7th argument to however you want to display it. But if you use lowercase for the other keywords, why would you use all caps for elseif?

Comment: Can you please explain little bit why we need to write 8 arguments? My structure does not have else if after the 1st if, then in macro why I need to define else if immediate after if? like that.

Comment: @Encipher With `\SetKwIF{If}{ELSEIF}{}{if}{}{else if}{else}{end if}` you define a whole set of macros. The complete syntax actually is `\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{endif}`. It will generate macros like `\If`, `\ELSEIF` etc., which you can later use in your algorithm. It has nothing to do with the structure of your code, the elseif is always the second argument in `\SetKwIF`, that's how `\SetKwIF` is defined.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.